# How to set runtime binding redirect on library

Tags: c#, dll

I have a bunch of .net dlls which are used by a Delphi application (through COM) and I got an error 'cannot load newtonsoft.json 6.0.0.0 version'

Because A.dll references newtonsoft.json 11.0.0.0, B.dll references HttpClient System.Net.Http.Formatting, which seems references newtonsoft.json 6.0.0.0.  And all dlls are in one folder which only have 11.0 version.

And all the existing solutions are adding bindingRedirect, but it only works for windows application and web application.  I have tried to add the bindingredict to A.dll.config, B.dll.config, but that didn't work.

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: It works if for .net application, but not when dlls are used as library.